# Copy file to external Download folder on Android 11

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions

I'm trying to copy a downloaded file from the internal download folder to the shared download folder.
It's working on Android 9, but not on Android 11.

I know, since Android 10 `File.copyTo()` doesn't work anymore.
I tried `MediaStore.Downloads`, but I can't get it working, since the source file is not readable.

Do I need some more permissions?

Thanks in advance.

```
W/WRITING TO DOWNLOAD: true -- /storage/emulated/0/Download
W/IS FILE: true -- /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/package/files/Download/app.apk
W/READING FILE: false -- /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/package/files/Download/app.apk
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: storage/emulated/0/Android/data/package/files/Download/app.apk: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

```kotlin
private fun startProcess(): Boolean {

    download()
    unzip()

    extDownloadFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
    intDownloadFolder = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)!!
    intApkFile = File(intDownloadFolder, apkFileName)
    extApkFile = File(extDownloadFolder, apkFileName)

        try {

            Log.w("CAN WRITE TO DOWNLOADS", "${extDownloadFolder.canWrite()} -- $extDownloadFolder")
            Log.w("IS FILE", "${intApkFile.isFile} -- ${intApkFile.absolutePath}")
            Log.w("SET READABLE", "${intApkFile.setReadable(true)} -- ${intApkFile.absolutePath}")
            Log.w("CAN READ", "${intApkFile.canRead()} -- ${intApkFile.absolutePath}")

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

                val values = ContentValues()

                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, intApkFile.name) //file name
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "application/apk") //file extension, will automatically add to file
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                val uri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values) //important!

                val outputStream = contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri!!)
                outputStream!!.write(intApkFile.readBytes())
                outputStream.close()

            } else {
                intApkFile.copyTo(extApkFile)
            }

            Log.w("DELETED FILE", "${intApkFile.delete()} -- ${intApkFile.absolutePath}")
            Log.w("COPIED FILE", "${extApkFile.isFile} -- ${extApkFile.absolutePath}")

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println(e.printStackTrace())
        }
}
```

```html
<!-- Permissions for the Android below 11 (R) -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    <!-- Permission for the Android 11 (R) and above -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />

    <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        ...
    </application>
```

```kotlin
private fun checkStoragePermission(): Boolean {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        //Android is 11(R) or above
        Environment.isExternalStorageManager()
        //ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    } else {
        //Android is below 11(R)
        val write = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        val read = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        write == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && read == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }
}
```

```kotlin
private fun requestStoragePermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        //Android is 11(R) or above

        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "requestPermission: try")
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.action = Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION
            val uri = Uri.fromParts("package", this.packageName, null)
            intent.data = uri
            storageActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "requestPermission: ", e)
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.action = Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION
            storageActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent)
        }

    } else {
        //Android is below 11(R)
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ),
            STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE
        )
    }
}
```

```kotlin
private val storageActivityResultLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "storageActivityResultLauncher: ")
        //here we will handle the result of our intent
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            //Android is 11(R) or above
            if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
                //Manage External Storage Permission is granted
                Log.w(TAG, "storageActivityResultLauncher: Manage External Storage Permission is granted"
                )
                startProcess()
            } else {
                //Manage External Storage Permission is denied....
                Log.w(TAG, "storageActivityResultLauncher: Manage External Storage Permission is denied...."
                )
                toast("Manage External Storage Permission is denied...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                showChangeLog(true)
            }
        } else {
            //Android is below 11(R)
        }
    }
```

```kotlin
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.isNotEmpty()) {
            //check each permission if granted or not
            if (grantResults.all { it == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED }) {
                //External Storage Permission granted
                Log.w(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: External Storage Permission granted")
                startProcess()
            } else {
                //External Storage Permission denied...
                Log.w(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: External Storage Permission denied...")
                toast(getString(R.string.ext_storage_perms_denied))
                showChangeLog(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit 1

I'm able to read/copy the downloaded zip file, but not the extracted apk.

### Edit 2

After adding `intApkFile.setReadable(true)` it worked.
I've modified the `startProcess()` code.